# Sharepoint in Extended recovery

Tags: sharepoint-online

I see since 1 day that SharePoint is in extended recovery, does mean I can't deploy apps? I keep on getting the weirdest errors and my app constantly fails to deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens during server/service maintenance. I think your only option is to wait and check the status.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/167113.aspx

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure since the description of the user experience did not match my errors. I'll wait until tomorrow